# Seeking Guidance on Implementing Geofencing in Flutter with Background Notifications

Tags: flutter, google-maps, heatmap, geofencing, geolocator

I am currently working on a Flutter project and have successfully integrated Google Maps to fetch user locations. However, I am facing challenges in implementing geofencing, heat maps, and background notifications.

**What I've Tried:**

Integrated Google Maps for fetching user locations.
Set up the basic structure of the Flutter project.
**Expectations:**
I am seeking guidance on suitable Flutter libraries or approaches for implementing geofencing, generating heat maps, creating fences on them, and sending notifications to users upon entering specific geofenced areas. My expectations include receiving advice, code examples, or recommendations from the community to successfully incorporate these features into my Flutter project. Any insights or assistance on Flutter geofencing, heat maps, and background notifications would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Have you tried using [google_maps_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_utils)? The `google_maps_flutter` also has a built in polygon and circle widgets. https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter-library.html#:~:text=for%20a%20Polyline.-,Polygon,-Draws%20a%20polygon for the heatmap, there is a library for that also. https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_heatmap

Comment: With that said, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) since it is recommended that you do your own research first and implement things on your own. When you encounter issues, that would be the time that you post a question here and as much as possible provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community could help you better.